# Trouble reading LAZ lidar files in R download from NOAA DAV

Tags: r, noaa, las, lidr

I am attempting to download the raw point cloud of a lidar acquisition from NOAA's Office of Coastal Management's Lidar database using R.  The data download without error, but when I read in the laz files as a LASCatalog, I get the following error:

```
WARNING: only 148 bytes until point block when trying to read 12423 bytes into header.vlrs[1].data
WARNING: only 0 bytes until point block after reading 2 of 3 vlrs. skipping remaining vlrs ...
ERROR: this file was compressed with an experimental version of laszip
ERROR: please contact 'martin.isenburg@rapidlasso.com' for assistance.
ERROR: cannot open lasreaderlas with file name 'C:\Users\SCMCKENZIE\Downloads\Test.laz'
Error: LASlib internal error. See message above.
Error in !x@PHB[["Global Encoding"]][["WKT"]] : invalid argument type
```

Doing some Googling, I believe it is related to this [this error](https://groups.google.com/g/lastools/c/x8wF-sijCDQ?pli=1), which suggests that it is not in fact an issue with LASzip, but rather an issue with downloading from NOAA's AWS server.  I found [this blog](https://geozoneblog.wordpress.com/2019/05/01/bulk-lidar-download-on-digital-coast/), whose comments suggest that it may be possible to download via FTP instead, but I have not been able to figure out how to do that.  Any advice on other ways to download these data would be greatly appreciated.  Below is a reproducible example of my workflow in R.

```
##install and/or necessary package##
if(!require(lidR)){
  install.packages("lidR")
}

##Download Text File of URLs with point cloud files##
download.file("https://noaa-nos-coastal-lidar-pds.s3.amazonaws.com/laz/geoid18/9305/urllist9305.txt", "lidarlist.txt")
lazlist<-read.table("lidarlist.txt")
download.file(lazlist$V1[9], "Test.laz")

test<-readLAScatalog("Test.laz") #Throws Error
test<-readLAS("Test.laz") #Crashes R
```

Apologies in advance for cross-posting

Answer (score 1):

lidR uses LASlib/LASzip from LAStools to read and write LAS and LAZ files. Your files are corrupted. Story ends here. You must find non-corrupted files, or you must try to reproduce with LAStools (using e.g. `lasinfo`) and report to `LAStools` to see if they have solutions to offer. Here in `lidR` I can't help you.